# How to disable an email account when the password has changed?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email

Is there a way to temporarily disable "Mail" for a given account when the password has changed other than deleting the account (see screenshot below)?

[image: Unable to disable Mail]

What cannot be seen on the screenshot is the following message:

> There was a problem accessing your account. Please re-enter the password for *[email address]*

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect from the network, then enter the password. The device can't check the password with the server, so enables the switches anyway, then you can switch the Mail toggle off to disable it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I've disabled both Wifi and Cellular, restarted my phone, but the switch is still disabled.

Comment: Sorry, I misread you answer. I disabled Wifi and Cellular, and tried to enter my password, but I got the following message: "Error Signing In - There is no connection to the Internet."